# Auto tagging in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, ios5, flickr

I just need to know is there any API which auto tags faces in the photos in the iOS? My requirement is we need to auto tag friends from facebook and flickr when we capture an image in the iPhone. Since we can get friends list from fb and flickr, but I am not sure how to auto tag the captured photos using these combined friends list? Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: This is not possible currently. There are various privacy concerns revolving around this.